# Where is custom NuGet feed url saved in my local solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, teamcity, nuget

I use TeamCity and have it create NuGet packages that my projects use.

I've often wondered where the path/url to that NuGet feed is stored in my solution?

As it doesn't seem to be anywhere that gets checked in and other developers can use from a fresh pull on a clean dev machine.. we seem to have to re-add it each time we setup a new developers environment.

Does anyone know where custom NuGet feed urls are saved in solutions / projects?

**Update :**

Just to clarify my query isn't about how to allow others to use the same feed, but more out of curiosity as to WHERE the feed url is saved for ME locally.

-- Lee

Comment: This is answered in [How to add the custom nuget feed to TeamCity build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548324/how-to-add-the-custom-nuget-feed-to-teamcity-build)

Comment: Cheers John that's exactly what I am looking for.. (c:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config). I wondered why I couldn't find it anywhere around the solution! 

If you write as an answer i'll mark it as the answer i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution file in Visual Studio 201x and select **Enable Nuget Package Restore**.

Once that finishes, you'll have a .nuget folder in your solution.  Uncomment the NuGet.targets Package sources section and ***add any custom nuget server address***.

If you do not want the nuget.exe to be included in your source control, add it to your ignore list and change the Download NuGet.exe setting to true.  Include the .target and .config file into source control and the rest of your team will now restore nuget packages upon build.

Comment: Thanks Werewolf but by query is not so much about ensuring the rest of my team can use the same feed but where is the path actually saved for me locally..

Comment: The nuget.exe downloads the .nupkg files to C:\Users\Werewolf\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache  You can add this in the nuget config section so you're able to build while off-line

Comment: Again that's not what i'm asking, I know you can do that here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx.

I've updated my question to clarify what i'm asking for

Comment: added bold to what I believe you are trying to ask, in the .nuget/Nuget.targets file and the <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' "> node.  If that's not what's being asked then there's two of us here wondering what it is you're actually asking for...

Comment: Thanks for your help Werewolf, however John Hoerr seemed to know what I was asking so i guess my question wasn't too obtuse :-)