# TeamCity and nuget.config selection

Tags: nuget, teamcity

While building a project using TeamCity I can see that in the nuget restore build step, teamcity uses nuget.config from the user profile instead only from the solution and has as a result some packages fail to restore.

```
NuGet Config files used:
[11:42:56][restore]     C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\ea6bd9299122e9cd\NuGet.Config
[11:42:56][restore]     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
```

I don't want it to use`AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` just the nuget.config that I specify as part of the solution `(C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\ea6bd9299122e9cd\NuGet.Config)`

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548324/how-to-add-the-custom-nuget-feed-to-teamcity-build